# Emoji don't display properly or don't display at all

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a game I use at the school I teach, it has some emojis that display fine in my computer :
[image]
but at the school computer I get only their outline(sorry for the photo):
[image]

I also use the hurricane emoji ️ that is not showing at all.

Is there a way to make sure the emojis will be shown properly or is there a way to set a fallback in case the emoji can't be displayed?

```css
:root {


  --blue: #5519ff;
   --dark-blue: rgb(1, 6, 77);
   --blue-outline-shadow: #3872b5;
  --blue-outline-highlight: #35a3cc;
  --yellow-outline-shadow: #c4bb00;
  --yellow-outline-highlight: #fff64d;

}



.emoji {
  text-shadow: none;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  font-family: apple color emoji, segoe ui emoji, noto color emoji,
    android emoji, emojisymbols, emojione mozilla, twemoji mozilla,
    segoe ui symbol;
  color: none;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px !important;
}

.Rtable-cell {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 0;
  padding: 1vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 4vw;
  place-items: center;
}

.letters {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--dark-blue);
  border-bottom: 3px solid var(--dark-blue);
  font-size: 4vw !important;
  /*  padding-bottom: 0; */
}

.blue {
  color: var(--blue-outline-highlight) !important;
  font-size: 5vw !important;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: var(--dark-blue);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0px var(--yellow-outline-shadow),
    1px 0 0px var(--yellow-outline-highlight),
    1px 2px 1px var(--yellow-outline-shadow),
    2px 1px 1px var(--yellow-outline-highlight),
    2px 3px 2px var(--yellow-outline-shadow),
    3px 2px 2px var(--yellow-outline-highlight),
    3px 4px 2px var(--yellow-outline-shadow),
    4px 3px 3px var(--yellow-outline-highlight),
    4px 5px 3px var(--yellow-outline-shadow),
    5px 4px 2px var(--yellow-outline-highlight),
    5px 6px 2px var(--yellow-outline-shadow),
    6px 5px 2px var(--yellow-outline-highlight),
    6px 7px 1px var(--yellow-outline-shadow),
    7px 6px 1px var(--yellow-outline-highlight),
    7px 8px 0px var(--yellow-outline-shadow),
    8px 7px 0px var(--yellow-outline-highlight),
    -12px -12px 2px rgba(49, 206, 99, 0);
}

.place {
  background-color: #fee140;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, 0%, #ffff7a #fff500 100%);
  border: 3px solid var(--dark-blue);
  text-shadow: var(--dark-blue) 0px -2px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 10px 1px rgba(1, 6, 77, 0.6);
  font-size: 4vw;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height:100px;
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fee140 0%, #fa709a 100%);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 10px 1px rgba(1, 6, 77, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="Rtable-cell letters blue">A <span class="emoji"></span></div>

<div class="Rtable-cell place disabled" >️</div>
```

Comment: Why do you add fonts to emoji class?